# Disable/remove entries from wifi applet in panel

Tags: network-manager

I'm running Ubuntu Mate 18. The builtin network adapter on my laptop appears to be faulty, so I am using micro USB one. How can I remove the entry of the faulty one from the network applet?

[image]

I do not want the first one (Ralink corp. ... Combo Adapter) to appear. I do not mind if it is necessary to disable that one for it to be removed.

I believe the adapter to be removed is

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

Comment: I suggest that we blacklist its driver which will remove it from the list. Let's start by identifying it. Please open a terminal and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Next, edit your question to show the result. I will then propose an answer.

Comment: Thanks! How did you know it could be identified by `0280`?

Comment: Many long, hard years in wireless. I know, I need to get a life!

Comment: Can't you not just disable it in BIOS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r rt2800pci
echo "blacklist rt2800pci" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Nice one, that's awesome